# How to revoke the applet permissions in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, certificate, java-applet

I have downloaded applet in Firefox, it was correct signed so I approved it.
Now I want to revoke this approval. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you how to do it in windows, but it will be pretty much the same on other OS's.

You should go to Control Panel and then find Java (It's called Java Control Panel), then go to security and to certificates and remove the certificate that you approved.